# one hot encode column at specific index at specific dimension

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have 3 dimension array of shape `(12000, 200, 5)` where 12000 is total number of samples, 200 is number of observations per sample, and their are 5 features per observations.  out of 5 features, feature at index 1 in 3rd dimension is categorical. How to one hot encode that features throughout all the samples and observations.

### EDITED

for example, if the original input has the dimension `(2,3,4)` is

```
[[[2 , 15, 23, 63],
[5, 23, 543, 94],
[8, 23 , 65, 25]],
[[3 , 15, 23, 57],
[12, 23, 543, 28],
[9, 23 , 65, 11]]]
```

required output should be

```
[[[0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0. , 15, 23, 63],
[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 23, 543, 94],
[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 23 , 65, 25]],
[[0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0. , 15, 23, 57],
[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 23, 543, 28],
[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 23 , 65, 11]]]
```

Comment: Add a minimal representative random sample data, say with a shape - `(3,2,5)` and show us the expected output?

Comment: ok. i do it in a moment

Comment: Also, what is the intended purpose? Is this being fed into a neural network?

Comment: @ChrisFarr yes the intended purpose is to feed into neural network

Comment: @Divakar question edited with an example of sample input and output.

Answer (score 0):

Here I found the solution.

```
X = (np.random.rand(3,2,5)*10).astype(int)
b=X.reshape(X.shape[0]*X.shape[1],X.shape[2])
c=to_categorical(b[:,0]) # column no 0
d=np.append(b,c,axis=1)
e=np.delete(d,0,1) # removing first columns from array, np.delete(array, columnNo/rowNo, axis)
X=e.reshape(X.shape[0],X.shape[1],e.shape[1])
```